# Is it possible to quit blender from the command line?

Tags: command-line, linux

Is there a way to quit blender from the command line?

I tried

```
killall -s QUIT blender
```

However, blender does not quit the same way as it does when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, and no `quit.blend` is saved.

Is there a way to properly and politely quit blender (with a saved `quit.blend`) from the command line?

Comment: I know it's not usable in the command line, but you could use `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()` in a python script.

Comment: @CharlesL Exactly :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could try with `wmctrl` instead of `kill`. However it's behavior may be application and windows manager dependant.

```
wmctrl -xc <WIN>
```

By default, `<WIN>` is treated as string to be searched in window title (`wmctrl -c blender` will close any window containing "`blender`" in the title). With `-x`, it will be interpreted as window class, so this invocation:

```
wmctrl -xc blender
```

... only closes any window having "`blender`" as its class name, which is usually Blender itself.

Comment: This makes me wonder, how does pressing the `X` on the window tell blender to close? I always assumed that it sent some signal, but now..

Comment: @gandalf3 Not a signal like those sent by kill, gui apps receive an event to closewindow which it then handles in it's event loop mixed in with other events like keypress or mousedown. If your quitting blender from the cli then there's a good chance your running blender in background mode - without a window to get a closewindow event.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sudo pkill -9 blender
```

Does the job under Linux.

Comment: Was looking [at this re killing firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/583246/can-i-close-firefox-browser-tab-or-firefox-browser-from-ubuntu-terminal) recently.  Using `killall` or `pkill` as suggested pretty much does as shown in question, instead of "gracefully" quitting blender as suggested in other answer here (which IMO could be accepted) , or in link re firefox.

Comment: Hello, a little bit more information about what the command does would be nice for newbies :)

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer! Though as batFINGER points out this KILLs Blender with signal 9 which leaves it no opportunity to save a `quit.blend` (the file loaded by the "restore previous session" button)